# how to handle the multiple ng-show and one ng-hide in angularjs if one condition is set to true and the left out ng-show to be false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a user hovers over the stars, I want to show the message `You rated <b>{{rate1}} star.</b><a ng-click="showMe()" class="modifyIt"><b  > modify?</b></a>`, and if the user has clicked on the rating I want to show 'Thanks for rating' (see html below for my logic). But after this if the user hovers again over the stars I want to show `You rated <b>{{rate1}} star.</b><a ng-click="showMe()" class="modifyIt"><b  > modify?</b></a>` again.

Issue is once rated, it shows 'Thanks for rating' always. How to fix this?

Please see my attempt at doing this below, and it would be helpful if someone can point out the error I have made. Thanks!

```
<div class="user">

  <uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="5" read-only="isReadonly" on-titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating" class="readOnlyRating "></uib-rating>


  <div  class=" arrow_box rt" ng-show="showRatings">
    <div class="ratingName">
      <h5><b>Give your rating here..</b></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="stars">
      <uib-rating ng-model="rate1" ng-click="rating(rate1)" max="5" read-only="isReadonly1" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating" class="readOnlyRating "></uib-rating>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" class="arrow_box rt" ng-show="ratevalue ">
    <h5 class="ratedPopover"> Thanks for rating </h5>
  </div>

  <div class="arrow_box rt" ng-hide="showRatings">
    <h5 class="ratedPopover">You rated <b>{{rate1}} star.</b><a ng-click="showMe()" class="modifyIt"><b  > modify?</b></a>
  </h5>
  </div>

</div>
```

### here is my directive file

```
scope.rating = function (rate) {

    scope.ratevalue = rate;
    if ($localStorage[localStorageRatingKey] == undefined) {
        previousRatingValue = 0;
        $localStorage[localStorageRatingKey] = scope.ratevalue;
    } else {
        previousRatingValue = $localStorage[localStorageRatingKey];
        $localStorage[localStorageRatingKey] = scope.ratevalue;
    }

    ratingService.update({
        companyId : scope.details._id,
        userRating : scope.ratevalue,
        previousRatingValue : previousRatingValue
    }, scope.details, successCallback, errorCallback);

    function successCallback(res) {
        // console.log("coming from callback");
        scope.rate = res.avgRatings;
        scope.reviewsCount = res.totalRatingsCount;
    }

    function errorCallback(res) {
        NotificationFactory.error('Failed to update the product rating...', res.data.message);
    }

};

scope.showMe = function () {
    scope.showRatings = !scope.showRatings;
    console.log("showme :" + scope.showRatings);
}

scope.hoverOut = function () {
    if ($localStorage[localStorageRatingKey]) {
        scope.showRatings = !scope.showRatings;
    } else {
        scope.showRatings = true;
    }
    console.log("hoverOut ShowRatings:" + scope.showRatings);
}

if ($localStorage[localStorageRatingKey]) {
    scope.showRatings = false;
} else {
    scope.showRatings = true;
}
```

Comment: The issue is not clear, what is not working here? The one thing I can also see is that the local storage value doesnt seem to get updated anywhere.

Comment: sorry for that. i have now just edited my code and given a brief description about my problem, you can now review my code

Comment: Sorry the wordings are still not clear. But you do need to update localstorage inside the success callback. I don't know if that is your issue though.

Comment: I would also suggest creating a jsfiddle or plunker with a working example of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using  ratevalue to show the message 'Thanks for rating', I would suggest using a flag like `hasjustRated`. In your code initialize this to false

at the beginning of this function definition: `scope.rating = function (rate) { ... }`

Also at the end of the success callback, add the following lines:

scope.hasjustRated = true;

Then on leave of hover, reset this value to false. I suggest adding a clear function for on leave that would do all the necessary steps when leaving hover.

Also what the showMe function does is a bit unclear.

Comment: You could accept my answer if that solved your question.